# Redirecting to Results page with react/redux by clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a 'Search' component that makes an API request to fetch a list of movies. At the moment, the 'Results' component renders beneath the Search component on the same page. I want to navigate the user to a different URL that only has the Results when they submit the form.

I have a button element to submit the form with. From the Networks tab in Google Chrome I can see that i am successfully fetching the correct data, however, I am not sure how to redirect Users to a Results page using a button element. Is it possible with 'react-router-dom?'

```
export class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  onChange = e => {
    this.props.searchMovie(e.target.value);
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchMovies(this.props.text);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form id='searchForm' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='form-control'
          name='searchText'
          placeholder='Search by Title...'
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button
          to={`/movies`}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<Redirect to="yourLink"/>` from reat-router package to do this (if you render this component, it will instantly redirect)

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`

Then

```js
this.history = useHistory();

onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchMovies(this.props.text);
    this.history.push('/movies');

  };
```

Comment: Do i put 'this.history = useHistory()' inside of the render() method? When i do... I get this error (I am using a Class component)
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: You should add this in `constructor`

Comment: @j_nguyen I faced same problem, its because, these hooks introduced to be used by functional components, when I changed my class to FC like 
const Welcome: React.FC = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
}

It worked